# No Microsoft Exchange account option in Pantheon Mail

Tags: pantheon-mail

There is no option to add my school Microsoft Exchange account, How can I?
Thanks Ben

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Evolution](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution) mail client. It has plugin to connect to Exchange servers.

```
sudo apt-get install evolution evolution-ews
```

Then when you're adding new account just select Exchange option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but all I have is a nonanswer answer, which is try using Thunderbird. I believe Thunderbird Will let you do this.

```
sudo apt-get install thunderbird
```

I find the default mail program to lack on some features, which is why I suggest trying this in Thunderbird. If all else fails you should use your internet browser to view your email.

Answer (score 0):

If your school Exchange server has imap enabled then you should be able to connect just fine - I have successfully connected Mail to Exchange at work.
In my case I needed SSL/TLS and a password for imap and STARTTLS + Use IMAP credentials for sending via SMTP.

Answer (score -1):

IMAP EN HOTMail

Servidor de IMAP: imap-mail.outlook.com

Puerto de IMAP: 993

Cifrado: SSL

SMTP

Servidor de SMTP: smtp-mail.outlook.com

Puerto de SMTP: 587

Cifrado: STARTTLS

Comment: Are these supposed to be examples of appropriate settings to use? If so, this only works for Outlook, not Exchange, and answers and questions should be in English only.

Comment: estas en un foro donde hablan todos ingles "ingeniero"